# How to share model attribute through controllers

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I have three controllers for ordering tacos, either through a menu or design custom ones.

This is the menu controller, we can order pre-made taco and then it redirects to current order where it shows the tacos in the order made.

```
@Slf4j
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/menu")
@SessionAttributes("tacoOrder")
public class MenuController {
    private final PreMadeTacoRepository preMadeTacoRepository;
    private final PreMadeTacoToTacoService preMadeTacoToTacoService;

    public MenuController(PreMadeTacoRepository preMadeTacoRepository, PreMadeTacoToTacoService preMadeTacoToTacoService){
        this.preMadeTacoRepository=preMadeTacoRepository;
        this.preMadeTacoToTacoService=preMadeTacoToTacoService;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public String getMenu(){
        return "menu";
    }

    @PostMapping
    public String orderMenu(@Valid PreMadeTacoList preMadeTacoList, Errors errors,@ModelAttribute TacoOrder tacoOrder){
        if(errors.hasErrors()){
            return "menu";
        }
        List<Taco> tacos = preMadeTacoToTacoService.convert(preMadeTacoList);
        tacos.forEach(tacoOrder::addTaco);
        if(tacos.size()==1){
            log.info("Processing taco: {}" , tacos);
        }
        else {
            log.info("Processing tacos: {}",tacos);
        }
        return "redirect:/orders/current";
    }

    @ModelAttribute
    public void addTacoToModel(Model model){
        Iterable<PreMadeTaco> tempo= preMadeTacoRepository.findAll();
        List<PreMadeTaco> preMadeTacos = new ArrayList<>();
        tempo.forEach(preMadeTacos::add);
        model.addAttribute("preMadeTacos",preMadeTacos);
    }

    @ModelAttribute
    public TacoOrder tacoOrder(){
        return new TacoOrder();
    }

    @ModelAttribute
    public PreMadeTaco preMadeTaco(){
        return new PreMadeTaco();
    }

    @ModelAttribute
    public PreMadeTacoList preMadeTacoList(){
        return new PreMadeTacoList();
    }
}
```

This is custom design controller, we can customize our own taco and it redirects similarly to current orders and it shows tacos in order

```
@Slf4j
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/design")
@SessionAttributes("tacoOrder")
public class DesignTacoController {
    private IngredientRepository ingredientRepository;

    @Autowired
    public DesignTacoController(IngredientRepository ingredientRepository){
        this.ingredientRepository=ingredientRepository;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public String showDesignForm() {
        return "design";
    }

    @PostMapping
    public String processTaco(@Valid Taco taco,Errors errors, @ModelAttribute("tacoOrder") TacoOrder tacoOrder) {
        if(errors.hasErrors()){
            return "design";
        }
        tacoOrder.addTaco(taco);
        log.info("Processing taco: {}", taco);
        return "redirect:/orders/current";
    }

    @ModelAttribute
    public void addIngredientsToModel(Model model){
        Iterable<Ingredient> tempo = ingredientRepository.findAll();
        List<Ingredient> ingredients = new ArrayList<>();
        tempo.forEach(ingredients::add);
        Ingredient.Type[] types = Ingredient.Type.values();
        for(Ingredient.Type type: types){
            model.addAttribute(type.toString().toLowerCase(),filterByType(ingredients , type));
        }
    }

    @ModelAttribute(name = "tacoOrder")
    public TacoOrder order() {
        return new TacoOrder();
    }

    @ModelAttribute(name = "taco")
    public Taco taco() {
        return new Taco();
    }

    private Iterable<Ingredient> filterByType(
            List<Ingredient> ingredients, Ingredient.Type type) {
        return ingredients
                .stream()
                .filter(x -> x.getType().equals(type))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

This is order class which shows current Order as it takes tacoOrder model attribute from session in either of them. The model with this class accepts one custom taco per request and a list of tacos from menu. (Ignore reviews they work fine)

```
@Slf4j
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/orders")
public class OrderController {
    private final OrderRepository orderRepository;
    private final ReviewRepository reviewRepository;

    public OrderController(OrderRepository orderRepository, ReviewRepository reviewRepository){
        this.orderRepository=orderRepository;
        this.reviewRepository = reviewRepository;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public String returnOrder(Model model){
        return "return";
    }

    @PostMapping
    public String saveReview(@Valid Review review,Errors errors){
        if(errors.hasErrors()){
            return "return";
        }
        reviewRepository.save(review);
        log.info("Review saved:\n By: " + review.getUser().getFullName() + "\n Comment: " + review.getComment()
        + "\n Rating: " + review.getRating());
        return "return";
    }

    @GetMapping("/current")
    public String orderForm(@ModelAttribute("tacoOrder") TacoOrder tacoOrder){
        return "orderForm";
    }

    @PostMapping
    public String processOrder(@Valid TacoOrder order, Errors errors, SessionStatus sessionStatus,
                               @AuthenticationPrincipal User user, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
        if(errors.hasErrors()){
            return "orderForm";
        }
        order.setUser(user);
        TacoOrder tacoOrder = orderRepository.save(order);
        user.addTacoOrder(order);
        log.info("Order submitted: {}", tacoOrder);
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("order",order);
        sessionStatus.setComplete();
        return "redirect:/orders";
    }

    @ModelAttribute
    public Review reviews(){
        return new Review();
    }

    @ModelAttribute
    public void addReviewsToModel(Model model){
        Iterable<Review> tempo = reviewRepository.findAll();
        List<Review> reviews = new ArrayList<>();
        tempo.forEach(reviews::add);
        model.addAttribute("reviews",reviews);
    }
}
```

It all works fine if I just order from menu or design a custom one. However, I want to be able to add both custom and from menu in one Order.

How will SessionAttribute work as both names are same in design and menu? (Spring will make two instances of tacoOrder and I will have two orders as far as I can tell.) I thought of using a super class annotated with @SessionAttribute and it makes one instance of that model attribute and then remove that from menu and design. Please let me know how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

use getAttribute

```
@Controller
public class SampleController1 {

    @GetMapping("/endpoint1")
    public String handleRequest1(Model model) {
        // You can access the shared attribute directly
        String attrValue = (String) model.getAttribute("sharedAttribute");
        // Do something with the attribute
        return "view1";
    }
}
```

Comment: in which controller i use that?